# How can I go about passing a Java Long Object to C in JNI

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

This does it for Java Strings :

```
public native Entity[] getALLEntityTYPES(String entityType);
```

---

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL
Java_my_jni_project_getALLEntityTYPE(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jstring entityType_) {

    const char *entityType = env->GetStringUTFChars(entityType_, 0);
```

---

How can I go about passing a Java Long Object to C in JNI:

```
public native String getEntityTypeByEntityGUID(Long entityGUID);
```

---

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you can pass long instead of Long, take a look here for full sample of passing primitive types

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-011/

If you want to pass Long (as Object) take a look here

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-020/

where sample code for getting values from Object is shown. Of course, in your case, you need to access fields of Long class.

**Update**

For unboxing (`Long`, `Boolean`, `Integer`, etc.) samples take a look here:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo055

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to pass the long value to jni you may use int64_t. don't forget to include stdint.h to make this type avalable. The java native signature would need to use long (not Long object)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution might be to use a `long` value rather than a `Long`object:

```
public native String getEntityTypeByEntityGUID(long entityGUID);
```

and declare your native function using the `jlong` type (cf the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html)):

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL
Java_my_jni_project_getEntityTypeByEntityGUID(jlong entityGUID) {
    // (...)
```